# When should I use Promises?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm still a bit lost when it comes to Play's Promises. In the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync) it says:

> The default configuration is tuned for asynchronous controllers. In other words, the application code should avoid blocking in controllers, i.e., having the controller code wait for an operation. Common examples of such blocking operations are JDBC calls, streaming API, HTTP requests and long computations.

So should I use a Promise for each JDBC call I do? This would essential mean to use a promise in nearly every action, since they somehow all use the database. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Promises are very usefull for having a thread dedicated to your controller (its importance is very high) doing "good" work : a work not expensive and/or in relation with controllers work.

In other terms, binding forms, etc., and managing Promises. But NOT doing jdbc calls (a lock happens so fast).

Example in a Controller class :

```
public static F.Promise<Result> doControllerWork() {
    return F.Promise.promise(
             () -> doBusinessWorkAndReturnSomething())
           .map(
             (returnedValue) -> ok(views...render(returnedValue))),
           );
}

public static ReturnType doBusinessWorkAndReturnSomething(){
   ...
   return something;
}
```

EDIT 1 :

If you have to manage several Promises in sequence :

```
public static F.Promise<Result> doControllerWork() {
    return F.Promise.sequence(
               F.Promise.promise(() -> doSomething1()),
               F.Promise.promise(() -> doSomething2()),
           ).map((returnList) -> {
                   ReturnType1 returnedElement1 = retrieveElement1(returnList);
                   ReturnType2 returnedElement2 = retrieveElement2(returnList);

                   return ok(views...(returnedElement1,returnedElement2));
           });
}

public ReturnType1 retrieveElement1(List<Serializable> returnList){
   int index = ...;
   // find by type using instanceOf, etc..
   return (ReturnType1) returnList.get(index);
}
```

And desining the work done in each Promise is (very) similar to multi-threading design.

Comment: Interesting. What makes you say that JDBC calls shouldn't be put in a Promise? I'm asking because the Play documentation says otherwise (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync). I'd like to know how little a task can be to put it into a Promise. According to Play's docu a JDBC call is already enough. But that looks like an overkill to me.

Comment: In thread controller : binding forms, etc., and managing Promises. In other threads : jdbc calls, business calls, etc.

Comment: This is not an overkill to put a jdbc call into a Promise due to the risk of blocking, latency. If you have a very simple case of jdbc call in a very small database, you could do your call in the thread controller. Here is other documentation [https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ThreadPools](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ThreadPools)